# Modal dialog not showing when more than one dialog is on the page

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have 3 separate links with each opening their own modal dialog. The links' `data-target` value is mapped to the dialogs' `id` attribute, eg. modal1, modal2, modal3

This is the code of one of those dialogs:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Some text...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All 3 modals have the same elements. The only difference is the `id` value, `model-title` and `modal-body` content.

The first 2 modals are shown as expected. The 3rd one not. It is not the order in which the modals are opened. As all 3 modals have the same, I can't figure out why it's always the 3rd one that isn't working.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

The problem occurs with Chrome. Edge displays the modal properly.

Comment: let's create a minimally reproducible example

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.